# Captioning the top and bottom of an image with imagemagick with some padding

Tags: bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to write quotes onto an image automatically. The script that I'm writing picks a random background and appends a quote on the top, and puts smaller on the bottom the quote from the person, with some padding.

The only issue, I'm not able to get the text to work properly. I'm trying to write centred text to a box on the top and then the caption of where it's from centred on text in the bottom, with some padding in between and on the sides. How can I achieve this properly?

Here is what I'm getting:
[image: Bad image]

**This is how I'd like to text to be arranged by filling these boxes centred: (note that I don't want the boxes drawn, just illustrating where the text ought to be)**
[image]

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the text
text="This is text that will occupy until a certain space. This will be long on here."

bottom="By Michael A. Leonetti"

echo $text

bgs="bgs"

image="${bgs}/$( ls "${bgs}" | sort -R | tail -$N | head -1 )"

echo "Using background image ${image}"

width=1024
height=768

usable_percent="0.95"
bottom_percent="0.1"
padding_percent="0.05"

usable_width=$( echo "${width}*${usable_percent}"|bc )
usable_height=$( echo "${height}*${usable_percent}"|bc )

bottom_height=$( echo "${bottom_percent}*${usable_height}"|bc )
padding_height=$( echo "${padding_percent}*${usable_height}"|bc )

text_width=$usable_width
text_height=$( echo "${usable_height}-${bottom_height}-${padding_height}"|bc )

convert \
    \( \
    -size "${text_width}x${text_height}" \
    -background none \
    -fill white \
    -gravity north \
    caption:"${text}" \
    -size "${text_width}x${bottom_height}" \
    -background none \
    -fill white \
    -gravity south \
    caption:"${bottom}" \
    \) \
    -composite \
    \( \
    "${image}" \
    -resize "${width}x${height}^" \
    -gravity center \
    -crop "${width}x${height}+0+0" \
    -brightness-contrast -30x0 \
    \) \
    +swap \
    -gravity south \
    -composite \
    +repage \
    "${bottom}.png"
```

Comment: Can't quite see what's gone wrong as I am not at computer but compositing the 2 captions together seems wrong. I would start with the main background image, then do the first caption in parentheses and composite it onto the background, then do the second caption the same way.